# Is ASP.NET MVC 1.0 Futures beta/preview code?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-futures

I understand that the "1.0" in "ASP.NET MVC 1.0 Futures" means that it is the ASP.NET MVC Futures built against the ASP.NET MVC 1.0 RTW (final/release to web). What I'd like to know is whether the Futures code is solid enough to treat as 1.0 / gold quality?

We're about to jump into ASP.NET MVC for the first time and it came up that we should consider adding Futures to our build. Problem is, if it's alpha code I'm wondering if it would be wise; stability is going to be very important for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the official release, not the beta. However, like any Microsoft product, 2.0 will always better if you can wait, but as far as your question concerned, it's the full release.

Answer (score 0):

Stability is good anough. The only problem is that Features might be cahnged in the future. Anyway, I use them in productino websites without any problems.